# Is there a preferred way of converting a SqlResultsetRowList to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, web-sql, ramda.js

When I try this in Ramda I get an Illegal Invocation exception:

```
var arr = R.map(r.rows.item, R.range(0, r.rows.length));
```

I can do it in two lines but then it seems even more of a hack:

```
var i = 0;
var arr = R.repeatN(null, r.rows.length).map( function() { return r.rows.item(i++); } );
```

What is the preferred method of accomplishing this?  Should I stick with a loop instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it:

`var rowArray = R.map.idx(function(row, i) { return r.rows.item(i); }, r.rows);`

That should map each row object into the output array `rowArray`.